# Android selected item from custom adapter listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hello I have an odd issue regarding my custom adapter listview.

This is my code,.

**DBHelper.class:**

```
public Cursor getAllStockCardListings()
        {
            Cursor localCursor =   
                    this.myDataBase.query(TBL_STOCKCARD, new String[] { 
                            KEY_ID, KEY_ITEMCODE, KEY_LOCATIONCODE, 
                            KEY_TRANSACTIONCODE, KEY_BEGINNINGBALANCE, KEY_ENDINGBALANCE }, 
                            null , null, null, null, null);

            if (localCursor != null)
              localCursor.moveToFirst();
            return localCursor;

        }
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
 class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter 
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //tvTransactionCode

        tvID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSerialNumber);
        tvItemCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemCode);
        tvLocationCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLocationCode);
        tvTransactionCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionCode);
        tvBeginningBalance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBeginningBalance); 
        tvEndingBalance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEndingBalance);

        tvID.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_ID)));
        tvItemCode.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_ITEMCODE)));
        tvLocationCode.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_LOCATIONCODE)));
        tvTransactionCode.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_TRANSACTIONCODE)));
        tvBeginningBalance.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_BEGINNINGBALANCE)));
        tvEndingBalance.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_ENDINGBALANCE)));

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_stockcard, parent, false);
     }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO onDestroy
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO onItemClick

    dbHelper.close();

    String selectedFromList = tvID.getText().toString().trim();

    Log.d("ID", selectedFromList);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewStockCard.class);

    i.putExtra("ID", selectedFromList);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

I have records 6 records and IDs are 1,2,3...6

But the odd thing here is, whenever I click on the item that has an ID of 2, I checked the logcat and the ID is 1 instead of 2. And I tried clicking ID 5, it's giving 6. There are only two records that give the correct selected items 1 and 6 and the rest are only giving 1, 4, 6. What seems to be wrong in my code? I really need your help guys. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar, I rolled back your edit, please use these to improve formatting, not make it worse.

Comment: @Leeor Really? I made proper edit.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar, please don't remove indentation from if() blocks or cross line assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @vipul mittal's answer

But I removed

```
  cursor.move(pos+1);
```

This is my final code:

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO onItemClick

    dbHelper.close();

    String selectedFromList = cursor.getString(
           cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_ID));

    Log.d("ID", selectedFromList);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewStockCard.class);

    i.putExtra("ID", selectedFromList);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

And also, getting the string value of long id makes it work as well such as this:

```
 String selectedFromList = String.valueOf(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the cursor reference in your `CustomAdapter` and get Id from the cursor

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO onItemClick

    dbHelper.close();

    cursor.move(pos+1);
     String selectedFromList = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_ID));

Log.d("ID", selectedFromList);

Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewStockCard.class);

i.putExtra("ID", selectedFromList);
startActivity(i);


}
```

Comment: thanks. I have to remove cursor.move(pos+1); to make it work.